# use if-else statement in java-8 lambda expression

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, java-8

I have a for-statement in java-7 and it's work fine:

```
Character cha = new Character(',');
String ncourseIds = null;
String pastCourseIds = null;
for (EquivalentCourse equivalentCourse : equivalentCourses) {
  if(equivalentCourse.getNcourse() != null){
    ncourseIds += equivalentCourse.getNcourse().getId()+ ",";   
  } else if(equivalentCourse.getPastCourse() != null) {
    pastCourseIds +=equivalentCourse.getPastCourse().getId()+","; 
  }
}
if(!ncourseIds.isEmpty() &&cha.equals(ncourseIds.charAt(ncourseIds.length()-1))) {
  ncourseIds = ncourseIds.substring(0, ncourseIds.length()-1);
}
if(!pastCourseIds.isEmpty()&& cha.equals(pastCourseIds.charAt(pastCourseIds.length()-1))) {
  pastCourseIds = pastCourseIds.substring(0,pastCourseIds.length()-1);
}
```

Now I want to convert my code to `Stream` & `collect` in java-8, I implement half of my business about filter not null `Ncourse`:

```
equivalentCourses.stream().filter(obj -> obj.getNcourse() != null )
                 .map(obj -> obj.getNcourse().getId()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

but I don't know to implement it's `else-statement`. any help?

Comment: Why do you use `Character` instead of `char`? This makes your code harder to read *and* wastes resources. Though, you don’t need it at all, if you replace `!ncourseIds.isEmpty() && ha.equals(ncourseIds.charAt(ncourseIds.length()-1))` with a simple `ncourseIds.endsWith(",")` and likewise, `!pastCourseIds.isEmpty() && cha.equals(pastCourseIds.charAt(pastCourseIds.length()-1))` with `pastCourseIds.endsWith(",")`. To collect two strings with streams, you can simple perform two stream operations.

Comment: @Holger already said it: use two stream operations (one for `getNcourse() != null` and one for `getNcourse() == null && getPastCourse() != null`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a stream call chain is complex make two streams - avoiding the conditional branches.

```
String ncourseIds = equivalentCourses.stream()
   .filter(equivalentCourse -> equivalentCourse.getNcourse() != null)
   .map(EquivalentCourse::getNcourse)
   .map(x -> String.valueOf(x.getId()))
   .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

String pastCourseIds = equivalentCourses.stream()
   .filter(equivalentCourse -> equivalentCourse.getNcourse() == null
          && equivalentCourse.getPastCourse() != null)
   .map(EquivalentCourse::getPastCourse)
   .map(x -> String.valueOf(x.getId()))
   .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

This also is code focusing on the resulting two strings, with an efficient joining.

By the way, if this is for an SQL string, you may use a PreparedStatement with an [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

---

Embellishment as commented by @Holger:

```
String ncourseIds = equivalentCourses.stream()
   .map(EquivalentCourse::getNcourse)
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .map(NCourse::getId)
   .map(String::valueOf)
   .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

String pastCourseIds = equivalentCourses.stream()
   .filter(equivalentCourse -> equivalentCourse.getNcourse() == null)
   .map(EquivalentCourse::getPastCourse)
   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
   .map(EquivalentCourse::getPastCourse)
   .map(PastCourse::getId)
   .map(String::valueOf)
   .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Nice use of the double-colon!

Comment: You can simplify by changing the order. First stream op: `.map(EquivalentCourse::getNcourse) .filter(Objects::nonNull)`, second stream op: `.filter(equivalentCourse -> equivalentCourse.getNcourse() == null) .map(EquivalentCourse::getPastCourse)  .filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: @Holger you are right, and also the getId could be improved with some class knowledge

Comment: @JoopEggen If `equivalentCourses` has huge number of elements, this is inefficient. Isn't? If so, is there any way to make it efficiently?

Comment: @Gibbs no, neither in O-complexity, neither in speed or space usage. In an old for-loop one could hold two StringBuilders and append to them in one loop and an internal if-else for appending to either StringBuilder. Making that two for-loops for each StringBuilder would be somewhat the same.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen I will give a try soon

Answer (score 1):

You could group by condition and then remap:

```
public void booleanGrouping() throws Exception {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("ala");
    strings.add("ela");
    strings.add("jan");

    strings.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.endsWith("a")) // using function Obj -> Bool not predicate
            ).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey() ? "Present" : "Past",
                            e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""))
                    )
            );
}
```

First stream group by condition, you should use `equivalentCourse.getNcourse() != null` second remap collections from value to string. You could introduce:

```
enum PresentPast{
    Present, Past
    PresentPast is(boolean v){
         return v ? Present : Past
    }
}
```

and change `e -> e.getKey() ? "Present" : "Past"` to enum based solution.

Edit:

Solution for `else if`:

```
public Map<Classifier, String> booleanGrouping() throws Exception {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("ala");
    strings.add("ela");
    strings.add("jan");
    // our ifs:
    /*
        if(!string.endsWith("n")){
        }else if(string.startsWith("e")){}

        final map should contains two elements
        endsWithN -> ["jan"]
        startsWithE -> ["ela"]
        NOT_MATCH -> ["ala"]

     */
    return strings.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Classifier::apply) // using function Obj -> Bool not predicate
            ).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            e -> e.getKey(),
                            e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(""))
                    )
            );
}

enum Classifier implements Predicate<String> {
    ENDS_WITH_N {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            return s.endsWith("n");
        }
    },
    STARTS_WITH_E {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            return s.startsWith("e");
        }
    }, NOT_MATCH {
        @Override
        public boolean test(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    public static Classifier apply(String s) {
        return Arrays.stream(Classifier.values())
                .filter(c -> c.test(s))
                .findFirst().orElse(NOT_MATCH);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is good solution only for `if-else` statement, but question is about `else-if` statement. In that case you need to perform two stream operation.

Comment: I see :) I will fix that (you need introduce a little bit different condition) when I back to my main PC :D

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

To add an alternative, here's what the code would look like to do the work with two `filter()` operations.  Note, this has the impact of iterating over the entire collection a second time, which may have a performance impact if this is a large collection.

I also went ahead and simplified some of the logic in regards to the string joining.  Correct me if I missed anything there.

```
final List<String> courseIdList = new ArrayList<>();
final List<String> pastCourseIdList = new ArrayList<>();

equivalentCourses.stream().filter((current) -> current.getNcourse() != null)
                .forEach((current) -> courseIdList.add(current.getNcourse().getId()));

equivalentCourses.stream().filter((current) -> current.getNcourse() != null && current.getPastCourse() != null)
                .forEach((current) -> pastCourseIdList.add(current.getPastCourse().getId()));

String ncourseIds = String.join(",", courseIdList);
String pastCourseIds = String.join(",", pastCourseIdList);
```

**Original answer**

For your use case, it may make the most sense to use the `forEach()` lambda.  This will be the easiest way to do the translation.

```
java.lang.Character cha = new java.lang.Character(',');

final StringBuilder ncourseIdBuilder = new StringBuilder();
final StringBuilder pastCourseIdBuilder = new StringBuilder();
equivalentCourses.stream().forEach((equivalentCourse) -> {
    if (equivalentCourse.getNcourse() != null) {
        ncourseIdBuilder.append(equivalentCourse.getNcourse().getId()).append(",");
    } else if (equivalentCourse.getPastCourse() != null) {
        pastCourseIdBuilder.append(equivalentCourse.getPastCourse().getId()).append(",");
    }
});

String ncourseIds = ncourseIdBuilder.toString();
String pastCourseIds = pastCourseIdBuilder.toString();

if (!ncourseIds.isEmpty() && cha.equals(ncourseIds.charAt(ncourseIds.length() - 1))) {
    ncourseIds = ncourseIds.substring(0, ncourseIds.length() - 1);
}
if (!pastCourseIds.isEmpty() && cha.equals(pastCourseIds.charAt(pastCourseIds.length() - 1))) {
    pastCourseIds = pastCourseIds.substring(0, pastCourseIds.length() - 1);
}
```

You can rewrite the code using `filter()` expressions, but it'll require a bigger re-working of the logic in the conditionals, which introduces the risk you might break something if this isn't tested well.  The logic changes are exactly what @Holger and @Ole V.V. reference in their comments to the original question.

Whether you use `forEach()` or the filters, lambdas cannot access non-final variables within the expression, hence why I added the `final StringBuilder` variable outside the scope of the loop.